# How to use kotlin-bom

Tags: maven, kotlin, maven-bom

I have a single-module maven project which uses a number of Kotlin libraries, and I'm trying to specify the kotlin-bom to ensure they all use the same version. I've got the following in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.20</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

However, when I do `mvn compile`, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar is missing.
```

How can I use kotlin-bom in a single-module project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your bom declaration to  dependencyManagment section

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.20</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```